# Communication between tabs or windows

Tags: javascript, html, browser, broadcast-channel

I was searching for a way how to communicate between multiple tabs or windows in a browser (on the same domain, not [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) without leaving traces. There were several solutions:

1. [using the *window* object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167965/how-do-you-communicate-between-2-browser-tabs-windows)
2. [postMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384)
3. [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows/4079423#4079423)
4. [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100336/sending-a-message-to-all-open-windows-tabs-using-javascript)

The first is probably the worst solution - you need to open a window from your current window and then you can communicate only as long as you keep the windows open. If you reload the page in any of the windows, you most likely lose the communication.

The second approach, using postMessage, probably enables cross-origin communication, but it suffers the same problem as the first approach. You need to maintain a window object.

The third way, using cookies, store some data in the browser, which can effectively look like sending a message to all windows on the same domain, but the problem is that you can never know if all tabs read the "message" already or not before cleaning up. You have to implement some sort of timeout to read the cookie periodically. Furthermore, you are limited by the maximum cookie length, which is 4 KB.

The fourth solution, using localStorage, seemed to overcome the limitations of cookies, and it can be even listen-to using events. How to use it is described in the accepted answer.

Comment: If you looking for communications across tabs on the same domain not origin, then local storage wont work as it is origin specific, broadcastchannel should not as well.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You may better use BroadcastChannel for this purpose. See other answers below. Yet if you still prefer to use localstorage for communication between tabs, do it this way:

In order to get notified when a tab sends a message to other tabs, you simply need to bind on 'storage' event. In all tabs, do this:

```
$(window).on('storage', message_receive);
```

The function `message_receive` will be called every time you set any value of localStorage in any other tab. The event listener contains also the data newly set to localStorage, so you don't even need to parse localStorage object itself. This is very handy because you can reset the value just right after it was set, to effectively clean up any traces. Here are functions for messaging:

```
// use local storage for messaging. Set message in local storage and clear it right away
// This is a safe way how to communicate with other tabs while not leaving any traces
//
function message_broadcast(message)
{
    localStorage.setItem('message',JSON.stringify(message));
    localStorage.removeItem('message');
}


// receive message
//
function message_receive(ev)
{
    if (ev.originalEvent.key!='message') return; // ignore other keys
    var message=JSON.parse(ev.originalEvent.newValue);
    if (!message) return; // ignore empty msg or msg reset

    // here you act on messages.
    // you can send objects like { 'command': 'doit', 'data': 'abcd' }
    if (message.command == 'doit') alert(message.data);

    // etc.
}
```

So now once your tabs bind on the onstorage event, and you have these two functions implemented, you can simply broadcast a message to other tabs calling, for example:

```
message_broadcast({'command':'reset'})
```

Remember that sending the exact same message twice will be propagated only once, so if you need to repeat messages, add some unique identifier to them, like

```
message_broadcast({'command':'reset', 'uid': (new Date).getTime()+Math.random()})
```

Also remember that the current tab which broadcasts the message doesn't actually receive it, only other tabs or windows on the same domain.

You may ask what happens if the user loads a different webpage or closes his tab just after the setItem() call before the removeItem(). Well, from my own testing the browser puts unloading on hold until the entire function `message_broadcast()` is finished. I tested to put some very long for() cycle in there and it still waited for the cycle to finish before closing. If the user kills the tab just in-between, then the browser won't have enough time to save the message to disk, thus this approach seems to me like safe way how to send messages without any traces.

Comment: can you ignore the remove event before invoking JSON.parse()?

Comment: keep in mind the event data limit, including pre-existing localStorage data. it might be better/safer to use the storage events just for messaging instead of shipping. like when you get a postcard telling you to pickup a package at the post office... also, localstorage goes to the hard drive, so it might leave inadvertent caches and affect logs, which is another reason to consider a different transport mechanism for the actual data.

Comment: @dandavis regarding ignoring remove event before invoking JSON.parse(), probably yes, checking ev.originalEvent.newValue: null, but I see no difference, parsing "null" value adds no significant cost.

Comment: @dandavis regarding data stored on disk, the main idea is that the local storage data is reset (emptied) right after it is set, so the browser doesn't store it on disk.

Comment: i did something related a while back: http://danml.com/js/localstorageevents.js, that one has an event emmiter base and "local echo" so that you can use the EE for everything everywhere.

Comment: @dandavis regarding pre-existing localSotrage data while considering data limit, this is very important point, thank you. However if the limit is reached then even sending 'a postcard' won't be possible. Thus it is on the programmer to ensure that he doesn't have other things in localStorage which would fill up the space.

Comment: depending on the application, you may be more inclined to call localStorage.clear() before adding data to it, in lieu of having to append a unique identifier to each message.

Comment: Gorgeous Answer.... This was a pain in the butt to figure out and TBH postMessage is good for what?  I will post an Angular 4 answer below.  But again thank you @thomas-m

Comment: Safari doesn't support BroadcastChannel - https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel

Comment: Also I think it is worth noting that using `localStorage.setItem('message',JSON.stringify(message));` and then `localStorage.removeItem('message');` will fire two `storage` events since there will be two changes to the local storage - adding and then removing something.

Comment: Just a heads up, you can also use shared workers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker (which has better support across browsers)

Comment: @Seblor SharedWorker does not exist in Microsoft Edge and Safari.

Comment: @ElisByberi Sure, I did not say it has support across all browsers. it is not an answer, just a tip so people would know it exists.

Comment: @Srikanth Safari now supports BroadcastChannel starting v15.4 (released March 14, 2022) https://caniuse.com/broadcastchannel

Answer (score 213):

There is a modern API dedicated for this purpose - [Broadcast Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

It is as easy as:

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

bc.postMessage('This is a test message.'); /* send */

bc.onmessage = function (ev) { console.log(ev); } /* receive */
```

> Data sent to the channel is serialized using the structured clone algorithm. That means you can send a broad variety of data objects safely without having to serialize them yourself.

It is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel) on all major browser, but you can find a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) that uses localStorage.

Comment: Wait, how do you know where the message is from? Does it ignore messages that come from the same tab?

Comment: @zehelvion: The sender won't receive it, according to e.g. this [nice overview](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/broadcastchannel). Besides, you can put into the message whatever you want, incl. some ID of the sender, if needed.

Comment: There is a nice project that wraps up this feature in a cross-browser library here: https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel

Comment: Have there been any public signals from Safari about whether or not support for this API will land in that browser?

Comment: @AturSams You check that MessageEvent.origin, MessageEvent.source or MessageEvent.ports are what you want.

As always the documentation is the best place to start:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent

Comment: It's not true that "any kind of object can be sent".  In Firefox v78, I tried sending the `window` object, and got the error "Object cannot be cloned".  So you can't use it to pass window references around.  (I was hoping to be able to do that so as to bootstrap direct 1-on-1 window-to-window communication).  In fact, according to the spec, only *Serializable* objects can be sent via `BroadcastChannel.postMessage()`.

Comment: I could be wrong - **please reply if there's a way to do this** - but I don't think you can reply to a broadcast message by initiating 1-to-1 communication.  (i.e. if A broadcasts to B, C, D, E, then D cannot reply just to A).  The `event.source` property looks promising, but in my experiments (Firefox 78) it's *null*, and without a `window` reference, you can't use the regular 1-to-1 `postMessage()` API.  (I suppose you could relay messages through a SharedWorker, given some method of uniquely identifying windows... but that seems rather inefficient and cumbersome).

Comment: @Doin, have you tried passing a [MessageChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API) port through the BroadcastChannel? Is a port serializable? If so, you can use `port.postMessage` to communicate with the sender directly.

Comment: @Mattias Nah, you can't do that, unfortunately.  I thought of it, but it's not possible because (as you guessed) browser objects (like ports) aren't serializable.  Roughly "serializable"="convertible to text and back", and the channel API only works with serializable data/objects.  One important reason for this is JS objects are NOT generally thread-safe, and yet the channel API can send data between windows running on different threads.

Comment: I second that "It's not true that any kind of object can be sent". `postMessage` sends messages using the structured clone algorithm, so only objects "structured cloneable" can be sent. Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone

Comment: Currently supported also (beside Chrome and FF) by Edge, Opera and Safari.

Comment: How can we pass "this" to the function ?

Answer (score 56):

For those searching for a solution not based on jQuery, this is a plain JavaScript version of the solution [provided by Thomas M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows/28230846#28230846):

```
window.addEventListener("storage", message_receive);

function message_broadcast(message) {
    localStorage.setItem('message',JSON.stringify(message));
}

function message_receive(ev) {
    if (ev.key == 'message') {
        var message=JSON.parse(ev.newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you omitted the removeItem call?

Comment: I was just focusing on the differences between jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: i always use a lib because of polyfill and possibility of not supported feature!

Answer (score 30):

Checkout [**AcrossTabs**](https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs) - **Easy communication between cross-origin browser tabs.** It uses a combination of the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) APIs to make communication much easier and reliable.

---

There are different approaches and each one has its own advantages and disadvantages. Let’s discuss each:

1. **[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

   **Pros**:

   1. Web storage can be viewed simplistically as an improvement on cookies, providing much greater storage capacity. If you look at the Mozilla source code we can see that **5120 KB** (**5 MB** which equals **2.5 million characters** on Chrome) is the default storage size for an entire domain. This gives you considerably more space to work with than a typical 4 KB cookie.
   2. The data is not sent back to the server for every HTTP request (HTML, images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) - reducing the amount of traffic between client and server.
   3. The data stored in localStorage persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

   **Cons**:

   1. It works on [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, data stored will only be able available on the same origin.
2. **[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)**

   **Pros:**

   1. Compared to others, there's nothing AFAIK.

   **Cons:**

   1. The 4 KB limit is for the entire cookie, including name, value, expiry date, etc. To support most browsers, keep the name under 4000 bytes, and the overall cookie size under 4093 bytes.
   2. The data is sent back to the server for every HTTP request (HTML, images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) - increasing the amount of traffic between client and server.

   Typically, the following are allowed:

   - **300** cookies in total
   - **4096 bytes** per cookie
   - **20 cookies** per domain
   - **81920 bytes** per domain (given 20 cookies of the maximum size 4096 = 81920 bytes.)
3. **[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**

   **Pros:**

   1. It is similar to `localStorage`.
   2. Changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site on the same window. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted

   **Cons:**

   1. The data is available only inside the window/tab in which it was set.
   2. The data is not persistent, i.e., it will be lost once the window/tab is closed.
   3. Like `localStorage`, tt works on [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, data stored will only be able available on the same origin.
4. **[PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**

   **Pros:**

   1. Safely enables [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access) communication.
   2. As a data point, the [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) implementation (used by Safari and Chrome) doesn't currently enforce any limits (other than those imposed by running out of memory).

   **Cons:**

   1. Need to open a window from the current window and then can communicate only as long as you keep the windows open.
   2. ***Security concerns*** - Sending strings via postMessage is that you will pick up other postMessage events published by other JavaScript plugins, so be sure to implement a `targetOrigin` and a sanity check for the data being passed on to the messages listener.
5. **A combination of [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) + [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**

   Using postMessage to communicate between multiple tabs and at the same time using sessionStorage in all the newly opened tabs/windows to persist data being passed. Data will be persisted as long as the tabs/windows remain opened. So, even if the opener tab/window gets closed, the opened tabs/windows will have the entire data even after getting refreshed.

I have written a JavaScript library for this, named [**AcrossTabs**](https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs) which uses postMessage API to communicate between cross-origin tabs/windows and sessionStorage to persist the opened tabs/windows identity as long as they live.

Comment: Using `AcrossTabs`, is it possible to open a different website in another tab, and get the data from it to the parent tab ? I will have authentication details for the another website.

Comment: Yes, you can @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: The biggest advantage of cookie is it allows cross origin same domain, which is commonly useful when you have a set of origins such as "a.target.com", "b.target.com" etc.

Answer (score 19):

I've created a library [sysend.js for sending messages between browser tabs and windows](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js/). The library doesn't have any external dependencies.

You can use it for communication between tabs/windows in the same browser and domain. The library uses BroadcastChannel, if supported, or storage event from localStorage.

The API is very simple:

```
sysend.on('foo', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
sysend.broadcast('foo', {message: 'Hello'});
sysend.broadcast('foo', "hello");
sysend.broadcast('foo', ["hello", "world"]);
sysend.broadcast('foo'); // empty notification
```

When your browser supports BroadcastChannel it sends a literal object (but it's in fact auto-serialized by the browser) and if not, it's serialized to JSON first and deserialized on another end.

The recent version also has a helper API to create a proxy for cross-domain communication (it requires a single HTML file on the target domain).

Here is [a demo](https://jcubic.pl/sysend.php).

The new version also supports **cross-domain** communication, if you include a special `proxy.html` file on the target domain and call `proxy` function from the source domain:

```
sysend.proxy('https://target.com');
```

(proxy.html is a very simple HTML file, that only have one script tag with the library).

If you want two-way communication you need to do the same on other domains.

**NOTE**: If you will implement the same functionality using localStorage, there is an issue in Internet Explorer. The storage event is sent to the same window, which triggers the event and for other browsers, it's only invoked for other tabs/windows.

Comment: Just wanted to give you some kudo's for this. 

 Nice sweet little addition that is simple and allows me communicate between my tabs to keep the logout warning software from kicking people off.  Nice job. I highly recommend this if you want a simple to use messaging solution.

Comment: Absolutely awesome, I'm going to try using this lib over the next month, and definitely come back and give a thank you on the github sponsor. Thanks for making this and it looks pretty well maintained. I'm going to be trying this instead of AcrossTabs, it seems more simpler your API and robust fallback to localStorage.

Answer (score 13):

Another method that people should consider using is *shared workers*. I know it's a cutting-edge concept, but you can create a relay on a shared worker that is *much* faster than localstorage, and doesn't require a relationship between the parent/child window, as long as you're on the same origin.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352279/inter-page-communication-in-www/35348415#35348415) for some discussion I made about this.

Answer (score 7):

There's [a tiny open-source component](https://github.com/jitbit/TabUtils) to synchronise and communicate between tabs/windows of the same origin (disclaimer - I'm one of the contributors!) based around `localStorage`.

```
TabUtils.BroadcastMessageToAllTabs("eventName", eventDataString);

TabUtils.OnBroadcastMessage("eventName", function (eventDataString) {
    DoSomething();
});

TabUtils.CallOnce("lockname", function () {
    alert("I run only once across multiple tabs");
});
```

P.S.: I took the liberty to recommend it here since most of the "lock/mutex/sync" components fail on websocket connections when events happen almost simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on this on my blog: *[Sharing sessionStorage data across browser tabs](http://www.ebenmonney.com/blog/how-to-implement-remember-me-functionality-using-token-based-authentication-and-localstorage-in-a-web-application)*.

Using a library, I created `storageManager`. You can achieve this as follows:

```
storageManager.savePermanentData('data', 'key'): //saves permanent data
storageManager.saveSyncedSessionData('data', 'key'); //saves session data to all opened tabs
storageManager.saveSessionData('data', 'key'); //saves session data to current tab only
storageManager.getData('key'); //retrieves data
```

There are other convenient methods as well to handle other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a development `storage` part of [Tomas M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230846/860099) for Chrome. We must add a listener:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", (e)=> { console.log(e) } );
```

Load/save the item in storage will not fire this event - we *must* trigger it manually by

```
window.dispatchEvent( new Event('storage') ); // THIS IS IMPORTANT ON CHROME
```

And now, all open tabs will receive the event.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not runt this event"* (seems incomprehensible)?