# JavaScript communication between two WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have two `WKWebView`s that load local HTML. They both have origin `file://` so it should be possible for the two `WKWebView`s to communicate with each other using [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230846/707381). I tried but I was not able to get cross-`WKWebView` communication working.

Is it possible for two `WKWebView`s of the same origin to communicate directly with one another?

Comment: What kind of data to be communicated? You can use ObjC or Swift to bridge between two webview.

Comment: @ElfSundae: Need to communicate a string. It's very awkward to do JS -> ObjC -> JS.