# Firefox v52 discontinued support using window.open() to detect existing/open windows?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Or perhaps it't just broken?

I've been using windowObjectReference = window.open('',strWindowName) for years to check if a user has already logged into out WebApp.

As of FF52 it now appears to be broken or intentionally removed.

It still seems to work (for now) from the parent window (opener), but many of our users get links to the WebApp in emails (or have created desktop shortcuts) - which fire off fresh non-opener requests.

Does anyone know if I'm mistaken in my userstanding of FF52 being broken?  Or perhaps a workaround?

Thanks so much for your attention.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open states that it is still an open standard. Firefox shouldn't have any problem with it. Check your code.

Comment: Is it possible that your copy of Firefox has upgraded to [multi-process](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

I agree that the Mozilla docs still claim that this still works.  Which is why I suspect that something went haywire over there and they broke something in v52. Also - my code for this bit hasn't changed for years - so it's not some new bug on my end.  And surprisingly enough MSIE and Edge still work.

And no I haven't upgraded to an offshoot version of FF, still the vanilla version.  As did the hundreds of our users who are now complaining.

Comment: Current "vanilla" 52.+ version _is_ multiprocess by default already and problem you observe could be possibly related perhaps. Check your `about:support` page as and/or fiddle with `bout:config` `browser.tabs.remote.*` prefs, as doc that Álvaro pointed to suggests: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Firefox_Release

Comment: Hmm.  So I might have to switch my methology to using [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox](message manager) to communicate between window instances then?

Comment: That seems to be for extension purposes only. Most viable way of communicating between windows/tabs in current browsers is FMoPW sessionStorage messaging; take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28230845/540955

Comment: Either way, have checked e10s-edness of your current browser and/or tried your use-case with `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` set to `false`?

Comment: Many thanks to all.  Especially myf.  Looks like [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage] localStorage is the way to go.

Comment: That feels like a job for [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Still, it won't hurt to figure out whether your currrent code stopped working because of pages being in different threads or it's some entirely different issue.