# Force one tab only on web app (e.g. similar to WhatsApp and Google Messenger)

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, session-storage, broadcast-channel

I have a strict requirement to only allow a logged in user to open my web app in one tab. I've noticed that WhatsApp and Google Messenger's web apps have implemented this. For example, trying to open those apps in more than one tab (be it on the same browser, different browser, or even different device) results in these warnings:

[image]

[image]

Anyone know how this is done? There must be some sort of sync happening between the server and the client to ensure that only one tab is open. But this would require a unique tab identifier, which [can get quite complicated to build reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169442/188740). Anyone know how WhatsApp and Google Messenger are doing it? Their technique seems to work flawlessly.

Comment: did u already find the answer or the solution??, please let me know, it would help me a lot!

Comment: @Fragmantedbin I haven't but I'm still keen to find a solution. Have you seen anything that would point us in the right direction?

Comment: did u already find the answer? please update, i do still need it 

Comment: @Fragmantedbin no solution yet unfortunately. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how this is done at WhatsApp and Google Messenger, but if you work with WebSockets (your post hast the tag "websocket", so I assume, you do) every tab has its single connection to the server, and if your users need to be logged in you could check if the user has already a open weboscket connection to your server.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I don't actually use websockets at the moment, but it is something I can introduce. I currently use gRPC via Firebase's Firestore, so that's another area I can pursue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have no experiences with Firebase and its Firestore nor gRPC, but maybe this approach helps you to implement something similar. Maybe JSON WebTokens are something other you could work with.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is whatsApp web or google messages does but i've been manage to do that with local storage to mark the tab, and im using storage listener to listen if there is any changes to the local storage, what these code would do is decide what the first tab gonna do.

first assign some key to the tab with unique id, im using rand function.

```
localStorage.initPage = rand();
```

it would make a key called "initPage" into the local storage, then add the storage listener it would detect if the new tab is making new "initPage" key

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
if (e.key === "initPage") {
    // action
}
}, false);
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for this. While this can detect multiple tabs open in the same browser, it won't detect a tab being open in another browser or another device.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution and it is a little different from WhatsApp. I will make first tab as main tab, it will listen to creation of any new tab and send closing message to them instantly.

If a tab opened and not receive closing message after 500ms, it will set self as main tab.

```
export class TabMonitor {
  tabId: string = '';
  closing: boolean = false;

  keepOneTab() {
    this.tabId = rand();

    localStorage.setItem('@tab:' + this.tabId, 'open');

    window.addEventListener('storage', this.closeSelf.bind(this));

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('@tab:' + this.tabId);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.closing) {
        return;
      }

      window.removeEventListener('storage', this.closeSelf.bind(this));

      // Listen new tab and close them
      window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {
        const key = e.key || '';
        const id = key.split(':').pop();

        if (id !== this.tabId && e.newValue === 'open') {
          // Send close message
          localStorage.setItem(key, 'close');
        }
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  closeSelf(e: StorageEvent) {
    const key = e.key || '';
    const id = key.split(':').pop();

    if (id === this.tabId && e.newValue === 'close') {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
      this.closing = true;
      
      alert('There is an active browser tab, this page will auto close.');
      
      window.close();
    }
  }
}

new TabMonitor().keepOneTab();
```

The only issue of this solution is that if browser or computer accentually shutdown, the storage key will not auto release. You may consider add timestamp to clear them regularly.

```
localStorage.setItem(
  '@tab:' + id,
  JSON.stringify({
    action: 'open',
    timestamp: Date.now()
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using firebase.

In this case you can simply add the online/offline functionality. Then make sure that the user is not online. If he is online then close the browser or do whatever you want.

Fragmantedbin's answer is not good because it would work if I use another browser or device, and you can simply bypass it by going to the dev tools and deleting the value.

Comment: Can you elaborate which online/offline functionality you're referring to and provide code examples?

Comment: This is a blog explaining it @JohnnyOshika https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system

Comment: Thanks @AdamBasha, but there are lots of problems with Firebase's presence technique. I documented it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/249#issuecomment-791199152), but as far as I'm aware they haven't fixed them.