# I need a reference to an existing window name for use by postMessage

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I am using chrome 58.  I do not want to use 
" var otherwindow = window.open('', 'targetwindow', '');" 
to get the reference since it opens a new "about:blank" web page.  I want to use an existing open window which internally I have already established a name via javascript using: 
" window.name = 'targetwindow'; "
Once the otherwindow exists I can then use otherwindow.postMessage( . . .); to send the message to the target window where the eventlistener exists with that named ('targetwindow') window.

I do not want to use an iframe.  I do not want to use parent/child.  I do not want to use anything other than an existing open and internally named window.

I have not found any W3C defined method for obtaining the required reference.

Also, I tried using "Broadcast Channel" instead and had no luck.

Comment: are these windows on same domain? Can use storage events if they are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows