# How to send data from one window to another window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please tell me how to send data from one window to another window?
I have one button on my parent window. On click of that button I am moving to another page (There is success button present in another page). When I click success button on child or another window I am redirecting to parent window. I want to print "success" text on parent window.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6IRDD0DHxK6A7mExWOUP?p=preview

```
$(function() {
  $('#f').on('click', function() {       
    // alert('ddd');
    window.open('a.html')
  })

   $('#succ').on('click', function() {        
    // alert('succ');
    window.open('index.html')
  })
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: above questions discusses it

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

on your parent page add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;    //to get previous url
   if(referrer == 'a.html'){
       alert("success");    // here i am showing an alert box with success message, you can print it inside a div or span as per your need.
   }
});
```

**NOTE: on Plunker replace "if condition" with this one:**

```
  if(referrer=='http://run.plnkr.co/Bwm0sBW4RRnrmWRA/a.html'){
       alert("success");    // here i am showing an alert box with success message, you can print it inside a div or span as per your need.
   }
```

and to send data along with it:

```
do something like this:
window.open('index.html','height=400, width=650, left=300, top=100, status=yes');
or
window.open("index.html?cid=hello");
```

That's it. :)

Comment: which one is your parent page? a.html or index.html?

Comment: parent is "index.html"  from that I move to "a.html"   ..From there I want to move "index.html" with success text

Comment: can we send data ...username ? any obj ? and get object here

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to the html page through url parameter. just change your code in script.js file. Hope it will help you.

```
$(function() {
  $('#f').on('click', function() {
    window.open('a.html?id=' + 123)
 })
 $('#succ').on('click', function() {
   window.open('index.html?id=' + 1)
 })
})
```

then you can fetch the id value form params.
Thank you

Comment: To read the parameters from url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to keep track of whether the button was clicked or not.

Whenever the user clicks on the button, add a new key (isClicked, for example) to the localStorage.

When the user lands on the main page, check to see if this flag is set. If set, show the success message.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button id="cta">GOTO Sub Page</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear Success</button>
    <script>
      window.onload = function(){
        var isClicked = localStorage.getItem("isClicked");
        if(isClicked){
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Success";
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("cta").onclick=function(){
       window.open("sub-page.html");
      }
      document.getElementById("clear").onclick=function(){
        localStorage.removeItem("isClicked");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<!--- sub=page.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button id="cta">Activate Message</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("cta").onclick=function(){
        localStorage.setItem("isClicked","true");
        window.open("index.html");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Sample Plunkr Implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVSVJoLgNFF61lMzRj5Z?p=preview)

PS: You can use localStorage to store/retrieve other page related values as well. You can even store JS objects by storing their string representations as given by JSON.stringify method