# Ruby Sinatra Sessions Across Windows

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I have a quick question about using sessions across different windows. I'm currently trying to create a login screen for a web app that I'm creating and I was wondering if this flow will work by enabling sessions:

1. Window A: User inputs basic account information and is stored inside sessions
2. A new popup Window B is open and user is authenticated via Google oauth. I store the token `session[:credentials] = generated_credentials`. User closes Window B.
3. Window A has access to `session[:credentials]`

I guess my question here is if step 3 is valid because I'm trying to essentially listen for a new cookie

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but I think that's where the solution will be.

Comment: thanks- had enough information for me to conclude a result

Comment: maybe you could post your working result here as an answer, or mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This will work. I guess sinatra has some listener that always updates the session even if it was updated from a child window.