# Unable to receive storage events in angular2 application

Tags: angular, browser, tabs, cross-browser, local-storage

I am working on communicating between all open tabs of my application for which I am following

[Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows#answer-28230846)

but I am not receive event

here is my simple component code

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'selector',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
})

export class AppComponent {
 constructor(){
       // listen event
       window.addEventListener('storage', this.message_receive);
       // to trigger dummy events
        setInterval(() => {
            this.message_broadcast({a: 'rhushi'});
        }, 1000);
}
    public message_broadcast(message) {
        localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(message));
    }
    public message_receive(ev) {
        if (ev.key === 'message') {
            let message = JSON.parse(ev.newValue);
        }
    } 
}
```

please correct me if I am making any mistake here

Comment: until and unless you change thr value of storage the event will not fire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `storage` event only triggered if `localStorage` value changes in other tabs.

In above code you are broadcasting the same json each time means values in `localStorage` are not changing. Storage event only fired if there is a value change happens in storage. Try sending different values.

Comment: Ohh gosh, thank you so much! tried half a day to find my mistake!