# POS Customer Display (Web Based Application)

Tags: java

I'm currently developing a java web based POS Application and I have come to the part of creating the Customer display.

How can I be able to do this in a java web based application?

Comment: You need to ask specific questions -- what have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using tomcat to run my java web application. I want to open another tab from the Main page but I want to somehow connect the two tabs to send actions to the second tab.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows

Comment: thanks for the help..