# How to intercept opening url with service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My goal is to prevent opening yet another window when clicking on email confirmation link, and instead have the SW inform the already opened tab with the code from the link.

Is there an API that would let us intercept opening the link from the mail and handling the event inside the service worker?

Comment: For clarification, are you talking about clicking an `<a>` that is rendered in an email document being displayed in a standalone email client (Thunderbird, Mail on macOS, etc) or a web client that is rendering your HTML based email document?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of related to your topic is [Web-based protocol handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers)

Comment: @zero298 Either. The goal is to prevent opening a second tab when the first has some state that the user already generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: The BroadCast API seems awesome @Aprillion and allows for communication between tabs. But it's not compatible with IE nor Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if you register the service worker first, for example the user has opened somehow your app page that registers a service-worker.

Consider the following simple page:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  Sample App
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below the content of app.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('./service-worker.js')
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log("Service Worker Registered");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err)
        })
}
```

And finally our service-worker.js file below

```
//Ran when SW is installed. 
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log("[ServiceWorker] Installed");
});

//Service Worker Activate
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log("[ServiceWorker] Activating");
});

//Fetch Events
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
  var keyParam = requestUrl.searchParams.get("key");

  if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin && event.request.url.includes('/confirmation')) {
          event.respondWith(
           //do something else
            new Response("ok this key is already used " + keyParam,  { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "MyOwnResponseHaha!" })
          )
  }

})
```

So to conclude first of all your user must open somehow the index.html file to successfully install and register the service worker. Once this is done, any request(from a link in an email or directly in the browser address bar) that will be directed to let's say

```
http://yourdomain.com/confirmation?key=1234567
```

will be intercepted by **service-worker.js** and instead the following result will be returned:

```
"ok this key is already used 1234567"
```

OBS: However there are so many problems that can go wrong with that, that I do not recommend pursuing this course of action. Like for example, how do you check if key is already used? or if the user opened index.html in Chrome, then the service worker will be registered in Chrome. If for example Edge is the computer's default browser, then when he will click on the email link, an Edge instance will open, and the Edge browser will not have a service worker installed so the above link will return 404... Try to find another way. but it is trully amazing how SW can be used as an app router.

Comment: Naah.. unfortunately the user is still gonna be left with a second opened tab. But then, even if the sw sends close message to the second tab, I don't see a way to focus the previous one.

Comment: If you don't want to open a second tab... then make sure the first tab is opened by a namedframe, meaning... the a href link must contain a target attribute with the tab's name likeso: <a href="mypage.html" target="customname">My First Link</a> . Your second link regardless of the href, must have the same target name. I.E <a href="mysecondpage.html" target="customname">My Second Page</a> . test these 2 links please and you will notice they will both load in the same tab/namedframe "customname" . Hope this helps you.

Comment: To conclude, I think your email link must contain a target attribute that will open a page with a service worker. The service worker will save the key value in Cache or in IndexedDB. The service worker will intercept all future requests of the type "/confirmation?key=1234567" and will check if the same key is already stored in Cache or IndexedDB, in which case it will alert the user that the key was already used and the account was already validated. if the user will click again on the email link, its content will load in the same page with no additional tabs.

Comment: I have no control over how would the first page be opened. Thanx for the effort, nonetheless.