# Is it possible to update content from a web page from another web page (offline)?

Tags: javascript

This is a project for offline editing.
I have two pages (html ones) on page Post.html I have a few editable text boxes.
I need to update Show.html page with content typed in editable text boxes from Post.html. 
Is it possible?
The idea is to allow a customer to edit/type some names from a page and update the content from another.

Comment: Do you have a local server, or are you working with file protocol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: The project is a simple HTML file with documentation on how to edit some content for a HTML/CSS profile template. Most webcam performers have no clue  how to edit the source markup . So i thought it will be easy for them the "approach" i've mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but where the file is hosted?

Comment: @Teemu in the same folder... 1 folder two web pages, Page A is used for edit and update content for Page B

Comment: Please re-read my first comment ...

Comment: @Temmu . I don't know exactly what to reply as I don't run a local server and I have no idea about _file protocol_  . Well... thanks anyway for your time. Much easier to  record a video on how to edit rather than searching for definitions to understand a question to a question. I'm not an expert in programming reason for which I've asked on this platform.

Comment: So, you've just saved some html files to a local folder? If that's the case, then you're using file protocol.

Comment: @Teemu indeed HTTP protocol (looked for a definition online)... This might help, [animated image](https://imgur.com/cSuG2VU)

Comment: ?? HTTP contradicts with the "animated image", which says you're using file protocol, i.e. the full URL is _file://c:/user/Post.html_ etc. The case is "_you've just saved some html files to a local folder_" ...