# Detect if a page is opened in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm implementing a "Go Back" button that redirect the user to the previous page or close the current tab if the page is opened in a new tab.

How can i detect (server side or client side) if the page is opened in a new tab ?

My solution is to pass a parameter (for exemple `"new_tab=1"`) in every `href` attribute of each `<a>` tag with `target="_blank"` so i can read that parameter in the page load event, but i hope in a quicker solution.

Comment: I think you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows).

Comment: Here is working example . : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfqdzn

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the `history.length` property to see the length of pages in the stack, with `history.length === 1` meaning a new tab.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: I don't see how this would indicate if the client has opened the new page in a new tab. What if once the new tab is opened, the user navigates?

Comment: Well once the user navigates, the tab wouldn't be considered a new tab and therefore the OP's Go Back button should work.

Comment: OP says that clicking back in a window that was opened in a new tab should close the window. So, if a new tab opens and the user navigates and then clicks back, the window should close. In your case, they would just go back to the previous page.

Comment: The way I read the OP's question is if there is no page to go back to, then the tab should close. I'm sorry if that's not the way you read it.

Comment: *or close the current tab if the page is opened in a new tab*

Comment: Scott Marcus's interpretation is correct. The most common scenario is a full postback in the opened page that increments `history.length`. Now i'm searching a way to link informations to a specific tab...