# Can Vuex dynamically share data across tabs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have an application that displays information and has a control panel component and a display component. The control panel has three views, there's the main display that shows the current element in the array, the left shows the previous and the right shows the next. (these are all placeholder photos by the way)
[image]
Then there's the main display component that displays the current element on another tab/page. The buttons work perfectly for this page, but I'd like for the buttons to change the display component on another page dynamically. So when I click the previous button, the current and other page should reflect that change. I've tried playing with vuex store, but that doesn't dynamically update the data and component on other pages. I would appreciate any insight that could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: (You could also use something like websockets to sync updates.)

Comment: Vuex would still be a way to encapsulate the data synchronization, no matter what method you use.

Comment: @ceejayoz hmm, I think I'll go in the direction of using vuex to store data but also using local storage to retrieve it in the other tabs. I guess I thought vuex would do it alone.