# Singleton Object in typescript lost Data on anchor tag target="_blank"

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

I have created a singleton class in Angular 6 typescript file.I am setting value of singleton object in component onInit() function.It works fine. but when I open new tab on clicking anchor with target="_blank" singleton class data is not lost.It is showing empty object.

```
export class DatatableSingleton{
    private static _instance: DatatableSingleton;
    private constructor() {
    }

    public static get Instance() {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    }
    public Datatable: Datatable;
}
```

I am not sure about the scope of singleton object,where it will be accessible for the new tab i have opened for same or not.

Comment: It is not accessible to new tab. I suggest you pass that data using query params or localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your Angular app is limited to the tab you are in. If you open two tabs of your app, you will have two different instances of your app, and therefore two different singletons.

If you want to share data between tabs, you might want to look into using cookies, local storage or parameters. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a new tab you create a new request to you application. So every single class will be created back again. If you need to store data in users browser and access it from any browser tab/window use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [websql](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) or [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).