# Wait for a newly opened window to close before continue

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using a loop with `window.open` inside it, and I'm looking for a way to wait for the previous window to be closed before launching the next one.

```
for(...){
          window.open('index.html', '_blank', 'nodeIntegration=yes');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Answer (score 1):

> Simple for loop will not work. This can be achieved by setInterval.
>   Please refer the code below.

```
var MyWin = null;//window obejct will assign in future
var i = 0;//Strating index of loop
var len = 5;//length of loop
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if ((!MyWin || MyWin.closed) && i < len) {
        MyWin = window.open("http://www.google.com/");
        i++;
    }
    else if (i >= len) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);//dont forget to clear interval
    }
}, 100);
```