# Angular application with oidc-client.js requires to login in second tab

Tags: angular, authorization, identityserver4, session-storage, oidc-client-js

I have authorization in Angular 8 handled by (oidc-client.js) + .Net Core IdentityServer4.

Everything seems to work fine, but when I open the same application in second tab then it requires from me to login again. IdentityServer4 has cookie so it's enough to click *Login button* and new token will be received without providing login/password again. Anyway it's still annoying.

Is it any way to solve it? I found [question on githubg](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/288) that might be partially helpful.

Some people suggesting that need to change token localization from *LocalStorage* to *SessionStorage*. But personally *SessionStorage* is better and I would keep it in that place.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc instead of oidc-client.js and it handles this scenario fine

Comment: @ElasticCode I prefer oidc-client.js since it is from IdentityServer Team, and is up to date, for example angular-oauth2-oidc is not supporting PKCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to use the *SessionStorage* (which seems to be correct) in several tabs, you could either copy its data between the tabs, for instance using `LocalStorage` event (see the code sample below) or [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), as described in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows), or implement autologin, like an alternative solution [does](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/82).

```js
(function(){

    if (!sessionStorage.length) {
        // trigger the event to get anything from other tabs
        localStorage.setItem('getSessionStorage', Date.now());
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {

    if (event.key == 'getSessionStorage') {

        //set and remove, so do not really keep the data in LS, but push it into event 
        localStorage.setItem('sessionStorage', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
        localStorage.removeItem('sessionStorage');

    } else if (event.key == 'sessionStorage' && !sessionStorage.length) {

        var data = JSON.parse(event.newValue);

        for (key in data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds nice, I'll check it and I let you know if it helped.

Comment: I was trying to find less complicated solution, but it seems that it has to be done by communication between tabs via LocalStorage.

Comment: as i mentioned, a real alternative is to implement autologin, then each tab performs the challenge silently. the solution from [damienbod](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) does that out of the box. I believe it's not a problem to do the same with oidc-client.js. nevertheless comparing these two libs a year ago, we found the angular one a bit more convenient when using with angular projects