# Javascript - toUpperCase in new window

Tags: javascript

This is how I want the code to be. When you write any word it will automatically change to uppercase using onkeyup. Also when user clicks on new window, the uppercase letters will be shown in the new window. I can only do the first part. How do I do this? https://jsfiddle.net/p3zea7Lu/11/

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <br /><br /> Type in your text: <br />
      <p>
        <input type="text" size="30" id="input" onkeyup="convertToUppercase()" />
      </p>
      <p id="output"></p>
    </form>

    <br />
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Open new window</button>

  </div>
  <script>
    function convertToUppercase() {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value.toUpperCase();
    }

    function myFunction() {
      var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
      myWindow.document.write("The word is:" + input);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try with this: 
mywindow.document.write("The word is:" + document.getElementById('input').value.toUpperCase());

Comment: FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows

Comment: @Manish I have rolled back the snippet because `window.open` doesn't work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **myFunction** to below.

```
function myFunction(val) {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("The word is:" + document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the input value in a separate variable and then pass it to the `document.write`

An example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgbrxk2c/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <br /><br />  Type in your text: <br />
            <p>
                <input type="text" size="30" id="input" onkeyup="convertToUppercase()" />
            </p>
            <p id="output"></p>

        </form><br />
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Open new window</button>

    </div>
    <script>
        function convertToUppercase() {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value.toUpperCase();

        }
        function myFunction(val) {
            var val = document.getElementById("output").textContent;
            var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
            myWindow.document.write("The word is:" + val);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML)">
    Open new window
</button>
```

```js
function myFunction(val) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("The word is:" + val);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It worked as it is. The onclick attribute does the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function myFunction(val) {
            var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
            myWindow.document.write("The word is:" +  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
        }
```

// Just replaced input with document.getElementById('output').innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Are popups enabled on that PC's Chrome? If they're not then the new window cannot be created hence `win` is `undefined`