# Events are not triggered when open pdf in external window

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have a problem with events, when open pdf in external window. They are not triggered even with 'viewerId' attribute. Here is my code:

#### HTML

```
 <a *ngIf="document.s3_link" class="document-title" (click)="openDocument(document)">{{ document.description }}</a
                    >
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer
        #externalPdfViewer
        viewerId="MyUniqueID"
        [externalWindow]="true"
        (onDocumentLoad)="highlightSearchTerm()"
    ></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

#### TypeScript

```
openDocument(document): void {
        this.getDocumentBlob(document.s3_link).subscribe(res => {
            this.externalPdfViewer.pdfSrc = res
            this.externalPdfViewer.downloadFileName = document.description
            this.externalPdfViewer.refresh()
        })
    }

getDocumentBlob(link): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        headers = headers.set("Accept", "application/pdf")
        return this.http.get(link, { headers: headers, responseType: "blob" })
    }

    highlightSearchTerm() {
        this.externalPdfViewer.PDFViewerApplication.findController.executeCommand(
            "find",
            {
                caseSensitive: false,
                findPrevious: undefined,
                highlightAll: true,
                phraseSearch: true,
                query: this.initQuery,
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: When you say "an external window" you mean a different browser window?

Comment: I mean different browser tab

Comment: I think you should give a better and more descriptive explanation of your issue. What is it exactly happening now and what are you exactly expecting? Otherwise, it's very hard to help.

Comment: I need to know when pdf is loaded. There is (onDocumentLoad) event for it. It works when I open pdf is the same tab. But when I try to open in external tab via adding [externalWindow]="true" - all events stop working.

Comment: I'm having exactly this issue, using the Angular "ng2-pdfjs-viewer" control, and my control is exactly the same tab... but no events get kicked off.  The pdf displays beautifully, but the onDocumentLoad() function doesn't get kicked off at all.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in documentation in one of the issues.

When you are opening PDF in a new window, events cannot be emitted back to former window.

Please see this SO: [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Documentation needs to be updated to reflect this. Using above techniques, it may be achieved, but that would require an improvement/implementation.