# how to persist value in a singleton state container in blazor web assembly on page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I practicing and learning `blazor web assembly`. I'm learning on the ways to communicate between the components. One such way is to use a state container. This works as expected however it does not sustain value on page refresh.

Here is my state container class,

**`AppState`:**

```cs
public class AppState
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered this as a `Singleton` instance in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
```

with this setup, I'm able to `@inject AppState` in multiple components and share the value like I can set it in one component and get it in another component. All goes well. When I refreshed, I lost the value in `SomeText` property.

After further googling, I noticed from this [article - Service Lifetimes in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/) that,

> Blazor is running on the client only and a full page refresh or
> opening the app in a new tab creates a new instance of the
> application.

But is there any workaround or solution to retain the value? All that comes to my mind is browser `localstorage`. Am I doing correct? Your suggestions please and correct me if I'n wrong?

Comment: How about session?

Comment: "F5" is like stop app and start it again. Session backend with token in SessionStorage or just store value in LocalStorage are some ways.

Comment: then just use Server in your scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reloading the page is the equivalent of shutting down an app and restarting it, anything in memory is gone.

I've not used it myself but I've heard Blazored/localstorage by @chrissainty is good. But the problem there is you'd have multiple tabs fighting to set the state to conflicting values.

So you'd either need inter-tab communication, which can be done with events
[Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

If possible though, use your client as the UI and have it communicate with a server (and then to a db) for persistence.

Comment: Reloading is equivalent to shutting down the app and restarting. This means program.cs will be executed everytime and all services will be registered again?

Comment: Yes, at which point you'd read state from wherever you persisted it too.