# Send information from one browser window to another

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a SPA that I cannot leave due to the fact that if the user leaves/refreshes, some information might be lost.

I want to implement the Instagram API, however the API requires that you browse to a different URL, login, receive a code in your URL, and then get redirected back.

Since I cannot do this directly from my site, I **must** open a new window to do this.

How can I retrieve the code from the URL in a separate window to send back to my site in the original window?

I have looked at websockets (need a server, so no) and WebRTC (on localhost, did not seem to work) already with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you save the information to `localStorage`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ideally, that's what I would do. However, I'm working within a larger site and I don't know the implications of just saving the state into localStorage. That would require a lot more research into that topic that I'd like to save myself from if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API allows using an `iframe`, you can watch what's happening inside the `iframe` or communicate from inside the `iframe` using `parent.instagramLogin(data)` (where `instagramLogin` is a function you defined outside the iframe).

An alternative option is to automatically close the login tab once the login is finished, and when the main tab is focused again (`window.onfocus`) send an `ajax` request to check if the login was completed. (and of course keep checking every time the event fires until you get a result or until it becomes irrelevant.)

**Update:**

I found a reliable way to communicate between open tabs, using `BroadcastChannel` if supported, otherwise `storage` event from `localStorage`. You can find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows), and someone in this link even made a small library to make it quick and easy.