# How to handle token set with multiple tabs in OAuth

Tags: reactjs, angular, oauth, authorization

I am building a new auth service and want to use a one time refresh tokens.

In theory it works fine but how do I handle sharing tokens between multiple tabs and not run into the race condition where multiple tabs try to acquire a new set of tokens using the same refresh token at the same time.

Since only one of these calls will succeed and other tabs will receive an error. At that point they will just assume the token is invalid and log the user out of those tabs which is not the desired experience.

Is there some standard frontend library that already solves this ?

Since I have read multiple solutions saying use a random variable on frontend so the chance of multiple tabs refreshing at the same time is reduced which in it self does not look like the most optimal solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store the token in local storage. It's shared between all tabs of the same domain. This assumes you're not on a timer.

If you are on a timer, i.e. each tab is fetching the refresh token at the time the old one is expired, then you would want to use inter-tab communication to sync up all the tabs.  Check out [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows).