# Showing tables in different screens

Tags: html, datatables, screen

Hello everyone I'm having a dilemma. Right now I have two tables side by side that we'll call table A and table B. I have 3 screens (It does not matter the size of screen at the moment). Screen one will be shown both Tables A and B side by side, while screen 2 will only show Table A. Screen 3 will show Table B. Since they'll be sharing data and communicating with each other what's the best approach to show one table in screens 2 and 3? Right now the HTML supports both tables in one screen. I know this might be vague but I don't know how to approach this situation. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you open your page in three different browser windows and add a UI element that allows you to choose for each window whether you want to see both tables or only Table A or B.
Then you need to add some logic to sync the table data among the windows. This will depend now on you actual architecture. If you use a web server to save and retrieve your data, each window can poll the data in a regular frequency or you use websockets instead. If your application is client side only there are also different ways to share data between tabs, e.g. [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows).